# Call 2 Futures in the same Action.async Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I'm a newby in Scala :( That's said, I'm fighting against Play framework Action.async and Future calls.

I'd like to call 2 Futures in the same Action and wait until they both compute to send their result in my view.

Here is the code :

```
    def showPageWithTags(category: String) = Action.async {
        val page = PageDAO.findOne(Json.obj("category" -> category)).map {
          case Some(page) => {
            page.content = page.content.byteArrayToString
          }
        }
        val futureTags = ArticleDAO.listTags
        Ok(views.html.web.pages.show(page, futureTags))
   }
```

with this defined functions :

```
def findOne(id: String): Future[Option[PageModel]]

def listTags: Future[List[String]]
```

I get this errors :

```
[error]  found   : Some[A]
[error]  required: models.PageModel
[error]         case Some(page) => {
[error]              ^
.../...
[error]  found   : None.type
[error]  required: models.PageModel
[error]         case None => {
[error]              ^
.../...
[error]  found   : Option[Nothing]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
[error]       optionPage.map {
[error]                      ^
.../...
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]
[error]  required: models.PageModel
[error]         Ok(views.html.web.pages.show(optionPage, futureTags))
[error]                                      ^
.../...
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]]
[error]  required: List[String]
[error]         Ok(views.html.web.pages.show(optionPage, futureTags))
[error]                                                  ^
```

I've tried map, for/yield, foreach to deal with Option and Future but there is always one of this errors which remains.

Yet the one Future call was working good before I add the "Tag" functionality :

```
  def showPage(category: String) = Action.async {
    PageDAO.findOne(Json.obj("category" -> category)).map {
      case Some(page) => {
        page.content = page.content.byteArrayToString
        Ok(views.html.web.pages.show(page))
      }
      case None => {
        NotFound
      }
    }
  }
```

**How can I call 2 Futures in the same action and wait until they both compute to pass them to my page view via Ok() ?**

Many thanks to any clarifications !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `flatMap` method of the `Future`.

> The `flatMap` method takes a function that maps the value to a new future `g`, and then returns a future which is completed once `g` is completed.

(from http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

So maybe try:

```
def showPage(category: String) = Action.async {
  ArticleDAO.listTags.flatMap { tags =>
    PageDAO.findOne(Json.obj("category" -> category)).map {
      case Some(page) => {
        page.content = page.content.byteArrayToString
        Ok(views.html.web.pages.show(page, tags))
      }
      case None => {
        NotFound
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: #Tabo : That's it ! `ArticleDAO.listTags` with `flatMap` should be called in first. Many thanks both of you !

Comment: @jeanjerome The order in which they are nested/called does not matter if one doesn't depend on the other--which they don't here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `map` and `flatMap` the `Future`s in order to access their results asynchronously. `Action.async` expects a `Future[Result]`, so you must map your `Future`s to that. Here's a simple way:

```
def showPageWithTags(category: String) = Action.async {
    val page = PageDAO.findOne(Json.obj("category" -> category)).map {
      case Some(page) => {
        page.content.byteArrayToString
      }
    }
    val futureTags = ArticleDAO.listTags

    page.flatMap { page =>
        futureTags.map { tags =>
            Ok(views.html.web.pages.show(page, tags))
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can clean this up using a for-comprehension, which is syntactic sugar for `flatMap`/`map`.

```
def showPageWithTags(category: String) = Action.async {
    for {
        pageOpt <- PageDAO.findOne(Json.obj("category" -> category))
            .map(_.map(_.content.byteArrayToString))
        tags <- ArticleDAO.listTags
    } yield {
        pageOpt.map { page =>
            Ok(views.html.web.pages.show(page, tags))
        } getOrElse {
            NotFound
        }
    }
}
```

I also took the liberty of simplifying your `map` on the `findOne` results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Your first proposal get `[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: models.PageModel
[error]             Ok(views.html.web.pages.show(page, tags))
[error]                                          ^` the second one `[error]  found   : Option[String]
[error]  required: models.PageModel
[error]     } yield Ok(views.html.web.pages.show(page, tags))
[error]                                          ^` That's what I fight against since 2 days...

Comment: I can't guarantee that this will compile because I don't know what the signature of the view is. I don't see anything that would cause it to infer `Unit`, unless something was copy/pasted incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
def showPageWithTags(category: String) = Action.async {

   for{
       pOpt <- PageDAO.findOne(Json.obj("category" -> category))
      futureTags <- ArticleDAO.listTags
      } yield{
          pOpt match {
           case Some(x)=> Ok(views.html.web.pages.show(x.content.byteArrayToString, futureTags))
           case _=> NotFound
                     }              
            }         
}
```